# Heavy performance issues after location changes

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc, technical-issues, performance

I bought *Skyrim* recently. As the title suggests, my performance drops after entering and leaving houses a couple of times.

My build is Intel i5 quad core processor, NVIDIA GTX 560 Ti from Gigabyte (stock-OC, manually downclocked to fix the CTD issues I had before with *Skyrim* and *BF3*), 4GB RAM

[A game tweaks website](http://www.geforce.com/Optimize/Guides/five-fast-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim-tweaks-guaranteed-to-make-your-game-look-even-better/) suggested that my slow hard drives might be a problem. A screenshot of a Windows Performance Index sample with the subtitle "This is likely to cause issues" showed the HDD with a performance index of 5.9, the exact same mine has, so I am considering purchasing an SSD.

I've tried different solutions: ENB Series, removing certain mods, checking my FPS Rate, monitoring my resources, .ini tweaks. It's all just fine, I don't see what I'm missing. Any thoughts?

Comment: This might be more suitable for SuperUser.com

Comment: @Renan Thank you for the advice, I'll post my question there as well.

Comment: @Renan Don't encourage users to double post. Explain the procedure of migration please, or flag it yourself if you're sure it's off topic for Gaming.

Comment: A lot of this background is more appropriate for a blog than a Q&A site.  I've removed the fluff to make the question more succinct.

Comment: Sorry, I have a tendency to write a lot. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Have you been using many mods? Some are known to leave garbage data in saves that slows the game down after the mod has been updated or removed. Try starting a new game with 0 mods and see if the slowdowns continue.

Also, make sure your mods are compatible with the version you're running.

Comment: Looks like my comment has been ignored. Here we go again: Although I didn't believe that this is the issue, I still tried it and got proven right. The problem still occurrs. Thank you for your quick suggestion though. I hope it's not a hardware issue, but I think it unfortunately is.

Comment: I'm not sure what comment are you are referring to. You've only mentioned removing "certain" mods, not trying a new clean game.

Comment: I was referring to my own comment, it didn't get submitted. Maybe I accidentally pushed the wrong button, just don't worry about it. However, I did try a new clean game after reading your answer.

Comment: Oh, derp, sorry. Can you tell us more about your HDD?

Comment: Well, it's as old as my PC, I didn't replace it yet, so it's approximately 2 1/2 years old. 1TB storage and I'm not even sure anymore whether it uses SATA or IDE, but I believe the first is the case... I'm not that good at hardware. [Here](http://img825.imageshack.us/img825/1862/windowsperformanceindex.png)'s Window's performance index. My system is German, shouldn't keep you from understanding it though. I've used [a tool](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/rkdisk.html) to get [these](http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/493/hddtest.png) results. What else information do you need?

Comment: I ran the same test and got about the same read speeds (4% better), but my cached read speed was nearly twice as much as yours, 300MB/s. Windows reports the same score as your HDD, 5.9 (also the "bottleneck", according to its scoring system). My computer plays Skyrim fine on middle-of-the-road settings, overall I'm not quite sure your HDD is at fault (or that a poor HDD could lead to the problems you're experiencing). You can find out the model of your HDD in Device Manager (RMB on Computer -> Managa -> Device Manager -> Disk Driver). My HDD is a 5 year old Seagate Barracuda.

Comment: Well then, sounds like my search for the actual problem is continuing. My HDD doesn't seem to be willing to provide a lot information, it doesn't say which vendor made it or which model it is. All it says is "ST31500341AS" in the device manager as it's name.

Comment: Google it and you'll get the goods. Here it is http://www.seagate.com/ww/v/index.jsp?vgnextoid=511a8cf6a794b110VgnVCM100000f5ee0a0aRCRD Thought Seagate seems to think your HDD is 1.5TB. It's pretty much the same as mine.

Comment: Hm, yes, should have thought of that myself, but I was tired and went to bed after I posted my comment. Anyway, I appreciate your help. It seems I do not need a new disk then. But what else could cause the issues..? I hope it's not because I don't use a "real" sound card? The on-board version was all enough for me since it sounds good, too, and I don't value sound too much.

Comment: It is a mystery. The issues you're experiencing would usually be associated with not having enough RAM, but 4GB should be enough. Have you tried flooring the quality settings? I suppose it's possible that your soundcard is somehow bugged, but it being integrated shouldn't be a problem in itself.

Comment: I did try lowest quality and it worked out just great. Then I went over to medium quality and the problems began. There isn't even a difference in high or ultra quality, except for a noticable FPS drop occassionally. Although, I'm not allowing Skyrim to use all the 4GB of course, since Windows 7 "naturally" occupies about 1GB, thus I only allow it to use 2 1/2, considering that I also have minor programs running in the background, like Notepad++. Maybe I should obtain some more RAM then... I suppose 2 more GB would satisfy.

Comment: @Derija: If I had to guess I'd say your graphics card was overheating, especially if you had to underclock it to run Skyrim and BF3 to begin with.  Does this issue still occur if you play for a long period *without* changing locations?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft No, this issue does not occurr if I, say, run around in the plains of Skyrim for 30 Minutes to 60 Minutes. It apparently did overheat before I clocked "back to normal", I technically did not "underclock" it since it was overclocked as I purchased it. I'd have to test loading large pieces of the map though.